# SwiftUI Simulator high CPU and memory usage

Tags: memory, swiftui, cpu

My simulated apps have started using a ridiculous amount of CPU and Memory. We're talking 700+ MB of memory and 99% of CPU. This would be concerning if it were my full app, but this often happens even when simulating the simplest of views.

It happened, for instance, while running this code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var show: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            show.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Toggle")
        }
    
        if show {
            Text("Showing")
        } else {
            Text("Not showing")
        }
    }
}
```

I know you probably won't be able to give a very specific answer, but what are the potential causes for this kind of CPU and memory usage? I've heard the term "Memory Leak" thrown around a lot but I'm still not sure how to actually detect and avoid it.

I ran this code in a different project and, as expected, the memory and CPU were normal. Why would this issue vary between projects? I'm using Firebase in the first and not in the second one, but Firebase by itself shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: If this code alone didn't cause the problem, it proves it isn't relevant. It's going to be somewhere else in your project, but that we can't debug as you have the tools.

Comment: So what kind of things should I be looking out for? Obviously I can't copy and paste my entire project here for you guys to debug, but do you have any suggestions for where to start looking?

Comment: And I can't test sections of it either... the code I pasted above proves that even though the code I'm running could be good, errors in code ran previous could still be affecting things (right?)

Comment: Learn how to use Xcode Instruments and debug with that

Comment: Assuming I find a problem, what can I do? Are they caused by random bugs in the system or are there ways to track the problem to specific lines of code?

Comment: I've used (or tried to use) Xcode instruments before, but I was unable to pin the problems I saw to specific lines of code

Comment: With instruments you can check what causes the memory leak. Follow some tutorial like [this](https://betterprogramming.pub/diagnose-memory-leaks-using-xcode-instruments-5692a6458020)